# bash loop until dig returns

Tags: linux, bash, dig

I am trying the following but it doesn't seem to give me my desired outcome, I basically want to run dig until I get a response at which point exit and continue with rest of script.

```
until dig +answer example.com > /dev/null ;do :; done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
until host example.com > /dev/null ;do sleep 1; done
```

Answer (score 3):

A couple of things:

1. dig will return a true result even if the record doesn't exist.

```
 $ dig +answer non-existent-record-$(date +%F).com && echo "Shouldn't see this" 
 # => Shouldn't see this
```

Instead, as Mircea says, use `/usr/bin/host`. Alternatively, you can test to see if the resolver returns blank using `[ ! -z "$(dig +short example.com.)" ]`. There is a very subtle difference in behaviour between `host` and dig when there's an AAAA record or MX record, but it may not affect you.

2. For `do :` instead use `/usr/bin/true` instead of :

TL;DR, Mircea's answer works for me, but just to be different, here's my take. It's different in that it doesn't pause for a second each test, which may or may not be what you want, and will not exit even when there are AAAA or MX records.

```sh
until [ ! -z "$(dig +short example.com)" ]; do true; done
```

Comment: Because there's no delay in the loop (the `sleep 1` in Mircea's answer), this will try the lookup over and over, as fast as it can. This is a waste of effort.

Comment: That's why I said this difference in behaviour may or may not be what they want.

Comment: I replaced `:` with `sleep 1` to limit the load on DNS server.